# What is the benefit of the StreamProvider._ constructor in async_provider.dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm learning Provider for Flutter's state management. I don't understand why to set the "_" constructor for StreamProvier. Is it possible to implement StreamProvider.value without constructor "_"?
Thanks!
Here is the code snippet and [the file link](https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/blob/master/packages/provider/lib/src/async_provider.dart)

```
/// Listens to [value] and expose it to all of [StreamProvider] descendants.
  StreamProvider.value({
    Key key,
    @required Stream<T> value,
    T initialData,
    ErrorBuilder<T> catchError,
    UpdateShouldNotify<T> updateShouldNotify,
    Widget child,
  }) : this._(
          key: key,
          delegate: SingleValueDelegate(value),
          initialData: initialData,
          catchError: catchError,
          updateShouldNotify: updateShouldNotify,
          child: child,
        );
  StreamProvider._({
    Key key,
    @required ValueStateDelegate<Stream<T>> delegate,
    this.initialData,
    this.catchError,
    this.updateShouldNotify,
    this.child,
  }) : super(key: key, delegate: delegate);
```

Answer (score 1):

This constructor is used mainly because of how MultiProvider currently works:
MultiProvider relies on cloning the widget.

The thing is, Providers (including StreamProvider) tend to have two public constructors, with different parameters.

That private constructor is therefore used as an implementation detail of that "clone" method used MultiProvider.